# What does it mean for a user to own a database fixed role?

Tags: sql

I have SQL Server 2012. When I create a user, in the "Owned schemas" screen one of the options is "fixed database role."

If I choose to grant an user permission on fixed database role, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

To easily manage the permissions in your databases, SQL Server provides several roles which are security principals that group other principals. They are like groups in the Microsoft Windows operating system. Database-level roles are database-wide in their permissions scope.

## [Database role in sql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx)

### [Roles In Details](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1900/understanding-sql-server-fixed-database-roles/)

Comment: thenks for the quick answer, but i dont understand if i owned a fix role, what this permmisiom grant me? i am the admin of this role?

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding SQL Server fixed database roles](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1900/understanding-sql-server-fixed-database-roles/) goes into greater detail. This is the link I suggest looking at first.

[SQL Server Agent fixed database roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) explains it fairly clearly, even if you're fairly new.

Basically, think of it like giving someone different keys to each room of your house, and one of the keys can open every door. Well, in a database, there are many, many functionalities and you have the option of creating roles to limit what users in certain roles can do. See the links for more clarification.